# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I have created table `Employee`

```
Create table Employee
(   
    FName varchar(20) Not Null,
    LName varchar(20) Not Null,
    SSN int Not Null,
    BDate Datetime,
    Address varchar(50),
    Sex char(1),
    Salary money,
    Super_SSN int,
    Primary Key(SSN),
    Foreign Key(Super_SSN) references Employee(SSN)
)
```

When i try to insert first row to ,

```
insert into Employee(FName,LName,SSN,BDate,Address,Sex,Salary,Super_SSN)
values('John','Smith',12345,'1965-01-09','Houston,TX','M',30000,33344)
```

I am getting the error like..

**Error:**

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "FK_Employee_Employee". The conflict occurred in database "Company", table "dbo.Employee", column 'SSN'.

Comment: Does the SSN of 33344 (taken from your example) exist in the table already? (edits were done to your question for formatting)

Comment: No, This is the first row in that table

Comment: Can the `super_ssn` column be `null` or does it have to be filled always?

Comment: Well then of course it fails. Your foreign key constraint says that the value there must be in the table. It can't be in the table because you are inserting the first row.

Comment: Please tell that SSN is some very poor abbreviation of a value that is NOT a social security number. And even more so, please tell me that the social security number is NOT the primary key.

Comment: @juergend it can be NULL..

Comment: I would also recommend you not store salary in the Employee table. You should have a EmployeeSalary table. That way you can track salary changes over time. The way you have it there is no way to know what somebody's previous salary was.

Comment: @SeanLange gosh I also hope it's not a Social Security Number. Also it's an `int`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to first INSERT record for **SSN '33344'** with **Super_SSN value as `NULL`**.

```
INSERT INTO  Employee(FName,LName,SSN,BDate,Address,Sex,Salary,Super_SSN)
VALUES (<FName>,<LName>,'33344',<BDate>,<Address>,<Sex>,<Salary>,NULL)
```

After that insert

```
INSERT INTO Employee (FName,LName,SSN,BDate,Address,Sex,Salary,Super_SSN)
VALUES ('John','Smith',12345,'1965-01-09','Houston,TX','M',30000,33344)
```

If **SSN '33344'** have any `Super_SSN`, update the SSN value (this record should be available in table).

Answer (score 6):

The error is likely thrown because there is a foreign key from `Super_SSN` to `SSN` column.  You cannot insert a value of `33344` into `Super_SSN` unless that value already exists in `SSN`.  Try inserting `null` into `Super_SSN` or inserting user `33344` first.